# Trying to embed youtube videos without links to youtube

Tags: html, iframe, video, youtube

I am trying to embed YouTube videos without links to YouTube but there is always the clickable watermark or the link in the control bar, even if I try to disable the control bar.
Here is the code:

```
   <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Ob_E91VUQZU?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: please, add your code

Comment: so you want the youtube logo to be hidden from the player..right???

Comment: @lal Yes im trying to hide it

Comment: @AlexKM the code is there? is it not appearing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YouTube will always take some credit for hosting your video (it's free because YOU advertise the brand name amongst other things etc). Logo is un-avoidable. The best you can try is something like this:

```
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ob_E91VUQZU?modestbranding=1&controls=0&amp;"
```

You can test by pasting the HTTPS link into a new tab and check if that's acceptable for you.

Otherwise the only way to lose any references to YouTube is to just host the same video file yourself on your own server and use your own custom made HTML5 or Javascript code to play the file.

Comment: well i know how to make a video player with html, but that means i need a file host that allows playback of uploaded files, ive gotten music to work on 4shared, ill try that. Thanks!
Also i want needing to get rid of the links/references due to strict forum rules

Comment: I'm guessing you are video file owner anyway, right?, so just get some free web hosting. Try **[Webs.com](http://www.webs.com)** for free filespace & HTML page hosting (player container). I don't condone downloads but If you need to grab the youtube video you can try **[this site](http://en.savefrom.net/)**... PS: You can upvote my answer if it was helpful (or even tick as correct). Thats true thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Add `?modestbranding=1` to your url. That will remove the logo.

**eg: "www.youtube.com/embed/video-id?modestbranding=0"**

> modestbranding
>
> This parameter lets you use a YouTube player that does not show a YouTube logo. Set the parameter value to 1 to prevent the YouTube logo from displaying in the control bar. Note that a small YouTube text label will still display in the upper-right corner of a paused video when the user's mouse pointer hovers over the player.

You can find all options on the [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) website.

Answer (score 0):

this is with sandbox where none of the links like related video works even if its ticked. Similar to the one below but with sandbox

```html
div style="border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); overflow: hidden; height: 800px  margin: 50px auto; max-width: 600px;">
<iframe scrolling="yes" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/snTlMy80c_E?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1&rel=0;modestbranding=1&showsearch=0" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px; height: 500px; margin-top: -60px; width: 100%;"    sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation" ></div>
```

This code will take out youtube name link with title and other links above. Hope you enjoy it.

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); overflow: hidden; height: 800px  margin: 50px auto; max-width: 600px;">
<iframe scrolling="yes" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/snTlMy80c_E?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1&rel=0;modestbranding=1&showsearch=0" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px; height: 500px; margin-top: -60px; width: 100%;"></div>
```